# Java NullPointerException with Class in Printf Statement

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception

Point exception is showing on line 27 (The printf statement at the bottom.)

Screen shot of cmd printout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvndw.jpg

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestLoanClass {
// Main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // Enter annual interest rate
    System.out.print(
        "Enter annual interest rate, for example, 8.25: ");
    double annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();
    
    // Enter number of years
    System.out.print("Enter number of years as an integer: ");
    int numberOfYears = input.nextInt();
    
    // Enter loan amount
    System.out.print("Enter loan amount, for example, 120000.95: ");
    double loanAmount = input.nextDouble();
    
    // Create loan object
    Loan loan =
        new Loan(annualInterestRate, numberOfYears, loanAmount);
        
    // Display loan date, monthly payment, and total payment
    System.out.printf("The loan was created on %s\n" +
        "The monthly payment is %.2f\nThe total payment is %.2f\n",
        loan.getLoanDate().toString(), loan.getMonthlyPayment(),
        loan.getTotalPayment());
}
}
```

I'm not sure what it's referencing. Below is the class if you need it. Thanks in advance.

Loan class:

```
public class Loan {
private double annualInterestRate;
private int numberOfYears;
private double loanAmount;
private java.util.Date loanDate;

// Default constructor
public Loan() {
    this(2.4,1,1000);
}

/* Construct a loan with specified annual interest rate,
number of years, and loan amount. */
public Loan(double annualInterestRate, int numberOfYears,
    double loanAmount) {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    this.numberOfYears = numberOfYears;
    this.loanAmount = loanAmount;
}

// Return annualInterestRate
public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
    return annualInterestRate;
}

// Set a new annualInterestRate
public void setAnnualInterestRate() {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
}

// Return numberOfYears
public int getNumberOfYears() {
    return numberOfYears;
}

// Set a new numberOfYears
public void setNumberfOfYears() {
    this.numberOfYears = numberOfYears;
}

// Return loanAmount
public double getLoanAmount() {
    return loanAmount;
}

// Set a new loanAmount
public void setLoanAmount() {
    this.loanAmount = loanAmount;
}

// Find monthly payment
public double getMonthlyPayment() {
    double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;
    double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate / (1 -
        (1 / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, numberOfYears * 12)));
    return monthlyPayment;
}

// Find total payment
public double getTotalPayment() {
    double totalPayment = getMonthlyPayment() * numberOfYears * 12;
    return totalPayment;
}

// Return loan date
public java.util.Date getLoanDate() {
    return loanDate;
}
}
```

---

#### Solution

Add `loanDate = new java.util.Date();` to class constructor.

Comment: Show your `Loan` class.

Comment: You need to show us the `Loan` class, definitely. My guess is that your constructor isn't actually setting everything. Also note that you shouldn't use `double` for financial values - use `BigDecimal`, or an integer number of cents/pennies/whatever.

Comment: loan.getLoanDate() is probably returning null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize `loanDate`, thus when doing `loan.getLoanDate().toString()`, it throws a NPE.

Initialize it in your constructor :

```
public Loan(double annualInterestRate, int numberOfYears,
    double loanAmount) {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    this.numberOfYears = numberOfYears;
    this.loanAmount = loanAmount;
    this.loanDate = new Date();
}
```

Also your setters are useless.

They should be (you might add some checks):

```
public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
}
```

And so on.

Comment: >.< Totally missed the initialization, and thanks for pointing out the mutators, this reminds me why I always do one or the other first instead of back and forth. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Loan.loanDate` is never initialised or assigned to.